# PHPMAILER Is there a limit to the number of attachments?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer, email-attachments

Do a READDIR and there are over 50 files in a directory.  Use a FOREACH loop to attach the files.  Only sends 20 attachments.  Does PHPMAILER have a limit to the number of attachments?

Comment: Please attach some code so we can see what you're doing in more detail (sometimes it's a small but only tangentially related problem)

Comment: $files = get_files ("/var/www/inet/rep/001/");

foreach ($files as $file) {
echo "<br>$file";
$mail->AddAttachment($file);
}

//Send the message, check for errors
if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

Comment: Is there a limit how much Outlook will receive?  Seems to work when sent to gmail.

Comment: Doesn't work to gmail.  Capped at 20 attachments.

Comment: Doing a foreach to get files in a folder.  Not attaching files.  Only working for first folder. foreach ($files0 as $file0) {
echo "<br>$file0";
$mail->AddAttachment($file0);
} It is showing the file names but not attaching.  Help Please!

Comment: foreach is not working.  I can attach a file, but if I try to attach all the files from a folder, nothing attaches.

Answer (score 0):

No, PHPMailer imposes no limit on the number of attachments you can have, but it's quite likely that some clients do. If you have that many items I'd recommend zipping them and sending them as a single file.